# FluentValidation does not autoregister Response/ReturnType

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation, clean-architecture

So I'm using Clean Architecture with Mediator, FluentValidation and AutoMapper (dotnet6).

I've registered the assembly via a empty interface like this :

Program.cs

```
    services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(IAssemblyMarker));
```

IAssemblyMarker.cs

```
    namespace Application.Common
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Just as the name of the interface says : it's an assemblymarker for the current project (class library project)
        /// This way it can be safely accessed without any typos
        /// </summary>
        public interface IAssemblyMarker
        {
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is that my ReturnType does not automatically validate like the InputType eventhough I implemented from the **AbstractValidator** class. So I need to manually create a new instance of the Validator for each ReturnType I have in my CommandHandlers.

The response base for all commands

```
public record BaseCommandResponse(bool SuccessStatus, Error? Error = null);
public record Error(string Message,string Code);
```

Has anyone come across this problem already with a solution ?

Comment: Why are you validating your return type anyway? Surely your code has just created it? It's not a standard thing to do.

Comment: @DavidG I added the ResponseType to the question. To answer your question: I have a validation rule that if the **SuccessStatus** is false my Error object cannot be null. And I want to prevent devs accidentally returning a instance of Response with the values false and null

Comment: I guess you could wrap the `IMediator` object with your own class that does validation.